# How to sync ongoing data from MariaDB 10+ to Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, replication, mariadb

I have a live sever running MariaDB 10+, right now I have to sync onging data to Oracle 12c database server. I tried Oracle GoldenGate, but it only works on MySQL (both 5.6 and 5.7) and MariaDB 5.5, I guess it because of MariaDB 10+ binlog format changed and no compatible with 5.5.

Also I checked tungsten-replicator, the official online document only mentions MariaDB 5.5 on Oct's release.

Anyone has a solution for this?

Appreciate for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Tungsten Replicator works with MariaDB Server 10.0 and greater. See the release notes: http://pubs.vmware.com/continuent/tungsten-replicator-3.0/release-notes-3-0-0.html (Support has been added for reading MariaDB 10.0.x events.)

But you're right, there probably is an issue with Oracle GoldenGate.